# how to change and add a phone number to BP address independent communication data

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I have to change address independent communication data for Business Partners (BP). For get data I'm using: BUPA_ADDRESSINDEP_COMMDATA_GET . I am looking for any function module like BAPI_BUPA_ADDRESS_CHANGE and BAPI_BUPA_ADDRESS_ADD, but for address-independent communication data. Or maybe can you tell me the tables where are stored address-independent phone and fax numbers?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address-independent data can be manipulated with functions like BAPI_BUPA_CREATE_FROM_DATA and BAPI_BUPA_CENTRAL_CHANGE. Have a look at those functions and related functions in the same function groups.

Comment: please one more detail... BAPI_BPUA_CREATE_FROM_DATA when i use obligatory parameters and tables for adding phone it was return exeption : External partner number 040034412D is already assigned to a partner 5100681536 .

Comment: Depending on the config, the partner/group (not sure which one anymore) will have the the BP number as external/internal assignment. If you are sending a BP number, try without.

Comment: if i use first filed BUSINESSPARTNEREXTERN it give me error Business partner already exists 5100681536 .. So I think BAPI_BUPA_CREATE_FROM_DATA  is only for creating all about BP. I have to add only address independent telephone number to existing BP. please do you have any idea how to do it? thx lot lot.

Comment: Please reread the answer carefully. There I mention also function BAPI_BUPA_CENTRAL_CHANGE. It is in fact in the same function group (BUBA_3).

Comment: sorry but i am only novice (new in this) so i do not know what do you mean about the "same function group.." maybe if you write me cook book.. :( .. thanx lof...

Answer (score 1):

To add or change phone data use the `TABLES` parameter `TELEFONDATANONADDRESS` of the function module `BAPI_BUPA_CENTRAL_CHANGE`.

```
*"  TABLES
*"      TELEFONDATANONADDRESS STRUCTURE  BAPIADTEL OPTIONAL
```